# Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'ip address'. This operation might require other privileges

Tags: c#, windows, security, networking, service

I am very new in C# and I am getting this error:

> Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '172.168.1.106'. This
>   operation might require other privileges.

when I try to start/stop a service that is installed in another computer that belongs to the same network of my computer. So does anyone have any punctual solution to this? Any tutorial? The service is installed in the other computer as Network Service.

This is how my code looks (essential part):

```
ServiceController servicio = new ServiceController(nombre, "172.168.1.106");

public bool ReiniciarServicio()
    {
        try
        {
            if (servicio.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                servicio.Stop();
                servicio.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
                servicio.Start();
                servicio.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be because you're doing it in C#.  Have you tried using `sc` on the command line?  Does the user account you're logged in with have administrator privilege on the remote machine?  Is the remote machine's firewall configured to allow access?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to impersonate the computer that own services. To do that
You could use code snippet below. In order to use the code below you should reference System.Management Assembly .

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Password = "password here";
options.Username = "username";
options.Impersonation =
    System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

// Make a connection to a remote computer. 
// Replace the "FullComputerName" section of the
// string "\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\cimv2" with
// the full computer name or IP address of the 
// remote computer.
ManagementScope scope =
    new ManagementScope(
    "\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\cimv2", options);
scope.Connect();

ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("ServiceName", "fullComputerName");
sc.Start();
```

Comment: My scope connected successfully but at `sc.Start()` raised the exception as OP mentioned !?

Comment: what is the exception